# How to transform degrees (angle) to facing number

Tags: c++, math, rotation, image-rotation, degrees

I have a image which contains 40 rotated images.

With image index starting at 0. 0-39 actually.

Here is the code which transforms 0-39 to degrees

```
int image_direction = 0; //Can be 0-39
int facing_degrees = (int)(360.0 * (-(image_direction- 10.0))/40.0);
while(facing_degrees < 0)
    facing_degrees += 360;
while (facing_degrees > 360)
    facing_degrees -= 360;
```

So yeah it can also give out negative degrees as well as degrees over 360. So thats why there is the 2 while loops.

Now I wish to reverse this process say I specify 90 degrees I would like to get back 0..

I was thinking of doing something like

```
 if(degrees == 90 || degrees >= 80 && degrees <= 99)
    image_direction = 0;
 elseif(degrees == 100 || degrees >= 91 && degrees <= 109)
    image_direction = 39;
//etc.......
```

Well I'm not good at mathematics, well I forgot about this kind of stuff.

I'm wondering how can you reverse the function that gives degrees from image_direction to run backwards in a plain equation to avoid the huge case of if statements.

Here is some results
[image: rotation results]

```
Image Index = 0 Image Degree = 90
Image Index = 1 Image Degree = 81
Image Index = 2 Image Degree = 72
Image Index = 3 Image Degree = 63
Image Index = 4 Image Degree = 54
Image Index = 5 Image Degree = 45
Image Index = 6 Image Degree = 36
Image Index = 7 Image Degree = 27
Image Index = 8 Image Degree = 18
Image Index = 9 Image Degree = 9
Image Index = 10 Image Degree = 0
Image Index = 11 Image Degree = 351
Image Index = 12 Image Degree = 342
Image Index = 13 Image Degree = 333
Image Index = 14 Image Degree = 324
Image Index = 15 Image Degree = 315
Image Index = 16 Image Degree = 306
Image Index = 17 Image Degree = 297
Image Index = 18 Image Degree = 288
Image Index = 19 Image Degree = 279
Image Index = 20 Image Degree = 270
Image Index = 21 Image Degree = 261
Image Index = 22 Image Degree = 252
Image Index = 23 Image Degree = 243
Image Index = 24 Image Degree = 234
Image Index = 25 Image Degree = 225
Image Index = 26 Image Degree = 216
Image Index = 27 Image Degree = 207
Image Index = 28 Image Degree = 198
Image Index = 29 Image Degree = 189
Image Index = 30 Image Degree = 180
Image Index = 31 Image Degree = 171
Image Index = 32 Image Degree = 162
Image Index = 33 Image Degree = 153
Image Index = 34 Image Degree = 144
Image Index = 35 Image Degree = 135
Image Index = 36 Image Degree = 126
Image Index = 37 Image Degree = 117
Image Index = 38 Image Degree = 108
Image Index = 39 Image Degree = 99
Image Index = 0 Image Degree = 90
Image Index = 1 Image Degree = 81
Image Index = 2 Image Degree = 72
Image Index = 3 Image Degree = 63
Image Index = 4 Image Degree = 54
Image Index = 5 Image Degree = 45
Image Index = 6 Image Degree = 36
Image Index = 7 Image Degree = 27
Image Index = 8 Image Degree = 18
```

Comment: Could you provide a list with some example mappings, e.g. 0 maps to x Degrees, 1 maps to y ... 39 maps to z

Comment: Well all I can say is that the function above works flawlessly. I have 40 images.. which are rotated in a full 360 degrees. image 0 being at 90 degrees, image 1 going less maybe 85, image 2 again less 75-70? i don't know.. But it does a full circle.. image 39 being 100 degrees. Clockwise

Comment: It would be very helpful not only for the question, but also your own debugging to wrap the above code in a look from i = 0 to 39, and printing the input index and output degrees to console. I'd advise doing that before proceeding as if you're not sure what the code is outputting its going to be hard to reverse engineer it.

Comment: No no.. the values the above function produces are fine, but I cannot use them in a array if you mean that, Because the degrees change in real-time. Sometimes its 90.. sometimes it's 91.. I would like it to be approximate.. so 90 and 91 would still equal image 0. Now that I think about this.. I think if statements are the only way to do this. I'll post a list of all angles to images index's.

Comment: what I'm saying is, your question really isn't clear about what the input code is supposed to do, hence finding an answer is going to be tricky. I'd suggest reformatting the Q with some sample expected mappings of Index->Degrees and clarifying special cases like the above.

Comment: Those online ocr websites really come in handy :) I put the text version as well.

Comment: +1 for the input / output mapping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your mapping of input to outputs, I pasted these into Excel and worked out that the formula to calculate degrees is as follows:

```
RawDegrees = 90 - (index * 9)
```

Then clipping this to 0...360 (wrap around using the while loop) you get your final degrees output. The formula to invert this is found by rearranging the above to make Index the subject

```
    RawDegrees - 90 = - (index * 9) --- 1
    RawDegrees/9.0 - 10 = -index    --- 2

    Therefore
    index = 10 - Degrees/9.0
```

This will give you the following mapping

```
    Degree  Discovered Index
    90      0
    81      1
    72      2
    63      3
    54      4
    45      5
    36      6
    27      7
    18      8
    9       9
    0       10
    351     -29
    342     -28
    333     -27
    324     -26
    315     -25
    306     -24
    297     -23
    288     -22
    279     -21
    270     -20
    261     -19
    252     -18
    243     -17
    234     -16
    225     -15
    216     -14
    207     -13
    198     -12
    189     -11
    180     -10
    171     -9
    162     -8
    153     -7
    144     -6
    135     -5
    126     -4
    117     -3
    108     -2
    99      -1
    90      0
    81      1
    72      2
    63      3
    54      4
    45      5
    36      6
    27      7
    18      8
```

All you need to do is perform a wrap around to clip the answer to 0..39, e.g.

```
index = index < 0 ? index + 40 : index;
```

to get the correct output.

Incidentally, your index to degrees code may be factorized as follows to get the same output (valid for inputs 0..39)

```
int facing_degrees = (int)(90.0 - (image_direction * 9.0));    
facing_degrees = facing_degrees < 0 ? facing_degrees + 360 : facing_degrees;
```

Comment: can't believe it's this simple `int index = 10 - Degrees/9.0;` wow that's some good logic you got there to work out the 9.0.. I did notice that all the degrees have the first digit `9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1` and second digit `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` thats how I memorized my multiplication of 9's table.  haha totally missed that.. ya seems from index 9 to 0 it's doing multiplication of 9.

Comment: @SSpoke - for problems like these sometimes looking at the numbers in Excel can give you an inkling of whats going on. I worked it out by eyeballing the numbers, noticing a "-9" relationship between each index:degree mapping and creating a column with formula `RawDegrees = 90 - (index * 9)` to check it (trial and error). From there its just algebra to rearrange into the solution. Another column in excel you can test this. The while loop part is often used when dealing in degrees to clip to 0..360. This is not part of the calculation, but just part of normalizing the output for sin/cos/ Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much and I hope you everything goes great for you too.

Answer (score 1):

hmm why not use something similar to the "percentage formula" with a little tweaking:

```
image_direction = (int)(((float)(degrees-90) / 360) * 40) % 40;
if (image_direction < 0)
    image_direction += 40; // for negative integers
```

Breaking down the formula; we divide degrees by 360 and multiply by 40 to get the correct image given a specified degree, we then use the modulo operator to keep the image_direction in the range 0-39 for degrees > +360 or < -360 and finally, if the degree was a negative one image_direction will turn out to be negative therefore adding 40 to it will correct the image_direction.

Hope this helps.

Edit: Oh sorry, I seemed to have missed the part about a degree of 90 == image index of 0, easy enough to add in here, just subtract 90 from the actual degree (code edited above)

Comment: Sorry more testing turns out it's going counter-clockwise? the 90 for index 0 is correct.. but then at 100 degrees it should be 39

Comment: Dr. Andrew Burnett-Thom wrote the solution in 1 line `int image_direction = 10 - degrees/9.0;`  I'll try to test all cases to see if anything is wrong.

Comment: Ok then, you could add this:

image_direction = (40 - image_direction) % 40;

below the above snippet of code, that corrects it but seems a little odd, is there no way of just rearranging your images to fit with the algorithm as it was before? If not just go with that.

Comment: Can't rearrange the images I'm actually making this mod a game in both generate images and reading images of the sprite set.